# How to install package

Tags: software-installation, 14.10

I need to install [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/vivid/libxext) package. How to do that?

Comment: Do you need the `2:1.3.3-1` version in 14.10?

Answer (score 0):

Run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libxext6
```

To be sure, run the command:

```
$ apt-cache policy libxext6

libxext6:
  Installed: 2:1.3.0-3ubuntu0.2
  Candidate: 2:1.3.0-3ubuntu0.2
```

Note the version.

[Take a look on launchpad of libxext package in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libxext)

> libxext-dev: X11 miscellaneous extensions library (development
>   headers)
>
> libxext-doc: X11 miscellaneous extensions library (documentation)
>
> libxext6: X11 miscellaneous extension library
>
> libxext6-dbg: X11 miscellaneous extensions library (debug package)
>
> libxext6-udeb: X11 miscellaneous extension library

And I suppose it should be already installed in your Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

To install libxext (named libxext6 on Ubuntu 14.10), first make sure that your local package list is updated with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And install the package with:

```
sudo apt-get install libxext6
```

Reference:

https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/vivid/main/libxext6/